# C# ThreadPool context switch logic

Tags: c#

I've been testing out some code that uses `ThreadPool` in C# and I noticed that a lot of unnecessary context switch occurs. While one thread is executing regular statements it gets context switched. They literally seem to be going back and forth for every line. I was wondering what the logic behind this was. Why would a thread get switched out for regular executions?

Comment: How did you notice that?

Comment: while debugging on visual studio?

Comment: Don't feel offended, please, but you are funny. See my answer

Comment: this is a good question, and I can see why you asked it. But @Daniel Hilgarth is right - it is funny ;-) The answers by @Daniel Hilgarth and @Dave Markle are corrrect.

Comment: no offence taken but I was hoping the debugger would replicate real-time behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads are supposed to execute simultaneously, running both threads at "the same time".  In reality, each thread (on a single processor computer) gets a finite amount of time (called a quantum) which is executed before a context switch.  This is a gross oversimplification, of course, but basically this is what happens.

When you run both threads in the debugger and step through (which is what I guess you're doing), the act of stepping through each statement causes it to exceed the time the thread has for its execution, and you get a context switch back to the other thread.

Answer (score 2):

While stepping through your code in debugging, every line takes WAY longer than during normal execution. That's why there are so many context switches. Normally, they happen multiple times per second.